# How to get multidimensional array from JSON in Typescript?

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, multidimensional-array

Here is a JSON array.

```
var cars = {
    "cars": {
        "john": [],
        "alex": [
            "ford"
        ],
        "hilton": [],
        "martin": [
            "ford",
            "ferrari"
        ],
        "david": [
            "Lamborghini"
        ],
        ...
    }

}
```

And I want to get array from this. How should I implement it in Typescript?
I tried several things, but none of them worked.
There is also a JSON array with only names as shown below, but I don't know how to use it.

```
var names = { 
    "names": [
        "john",
        "alex",
        "hilton",
        "martin",
        "david",
        ...
    ]
}
```

I tried like bellow, but it doesn't work.

```
let aryCars: string[][] = [];
names.map((name: string) => {
    cars[name].map((car: string) => {
        aryCars[name].push(car);
    });
});
```

But following error occur.

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.`

Please let me know if you know how.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably due to these lines:

```
let aryCars: string[][] = [];

aryCars[name].push(car);
```

You've declared `aryCars` as an array, which implicitly has number indexes, but you're indexing using the string `name`.

Perhaps you actually want `aryCars` to look like this:

```
const aryCars: { [key:string]: string[] } = {};
```

which is an object that has string keys, and an array of strings as values.

Then your code would be:

```
const aryCars: { [key:string]: string[] } = {};
names.forEach((name: string) => {
    aryCars[name] = cars[name]
});
```

But note that the `names` you showed is an object called `names` with a property also called `names` which would mean you would have to do:

```
names.names.forEach(...)
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, then please show what you expect the output to be.

Comment: Thank you for the easy-to-understand explanation. That's works.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays cannot have string indexes. Use an object type instead, for example:

```js
let aryCars: {
    [key: string]: string
} = {};
```

You can then access the object with array notation.